# Is there any possible way to make Bar of Pie in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I want to render **Bar of Pie** on using **Highcharts**. I went through page 10 of Google search with different keyword combination, but couldn't find any solution. Can anyone please help me?

Here's the picture of "Bar of Pie Chart" which can be easily made through Excel.

[image]

Pic source: https://www.officetooltips.com/

Comment: combine pie and column chart and on select of a pie update series values of column chart. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan Did that. But, it didn't turn out to be as I expected. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/girisagar46/ywtx5jwu/7/

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this **live demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/y62L2hdk/

I hid both axes and used `pointWidth` to decrease the width of the column. `load` event handles a very simplified mechanism of rendering the connector lines:

```
  load: function() {
    var chart = this;
    piePoint = chart.series[2].points[0],
      columnPointTop = chart.series[0].points[0],
      columnPointBottom = chart.series[1].points[0],
      arcPathArr = piePoint.graphic.d.split(" "),
      renderer = chart.renderer,
      pathAttrs = {
        'stroke-width': 1,
        stroke: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      };

    // extracting paths from pie point path (arc)
    var firstPieCorner = arcPathArr.slice(0, 3),
      secondPieCorner = arcPathArr.slice(4, 6);

    firstPieCorner[1] = new Number(firstPieCorner[1]) + chart.plotLeft;
    firstPieCorner[2] = new Number(firstPieCorner[2]) + chart.plotTop;

    secondPieCorner.unshift("M");
    secondPieCorner[1] = new Number(secondPieCorner[1]) + firstPieCorner[1];
    secondPieCorner[2] = new Number(secondPieCorner[2]) + firstPieCorner[2];

    // top connector
    renderer.path(firstPieCorner.concat(["L", columnPointTop.shapeArgs.x + chart.plotLeft, columnPointTop.shapeArgs.y + chart.plotTop]))
      .attr(pathAttrs)
      .add();

    // upper connector
    renderer.path(secondPieCorner.concat(["L", columnPointBottom.shapeArgs.x + chart.plotLeft, columnPointBottom.shapeArgs.y + columnPointBottom.shapeArgs.height + chart.plotTop]))
      .attr(pathAttrs)
      .add();
  }
```

This code serves only for example purposes - it needs to be improved to make connectors responsive.

---

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.maxPointWidth
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.visible